# How to interface 6 HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensors to Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, gpio, interface, distance

I am a beginner to Rasberry Pi and working on a parking warning system for a go-kart. The plan is to use 6 ultrasonic sensors (3 at the front of the kart, wired to one of the breadboards, and 3 at the back, wired to the other breadboard) to achieve distance warnings when obstacles get too close to each respective sensor. I'd like to note that I would like to wire the ultrasonic sensors to the breadboards and **NOT **attatch the sensors onto the breadboards directly. I've tried wiring 2, but can someone please explain how I can wire 6 ultrasonic sensors (and please be descriptive so it is easy to follow) to a Rasberry Pi 4 using the following equipment:

- Rasberry Pi 4
- Female to Male Jumper Wires
- HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Distance    Sensor (x6)
- 1kΩ Resistors
- 2kΩ Resistors
- Full sized breadboard (x2)

I understand that in order to achieve three ultrasonic sensors on a single breadboard, I must connect them in parallel. However, I am confused as to if I can wire multiple VCCs and Grounds of different ultrasonic sensors to the same + and - rail, or if they have to be on opposite sides of the breadboard to work

Comment: Unsure of your intention: *"opposite sides of the breadboard"*. All the ultrasonic transducer **Vcc** are tied together, and go to +5V supply. And all the ultrasonic transducer **GND** are tied together and go to the return line of the +5V supply (you might call this *common GND*). This *common GND*  is also wired to Pi's **GND**. How you physically connect these lines is up to you - via a breadboard if you wish. We generally follow schematic wiring diagrams that don't show a breadboard.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I really appreciate it. I understand the concept now. However, I tried setting up two different breadboards (for the front and back of the cart) which are supplied by the 5V power pins respectively (2 and 4). However, when both are plugged in, the second sensor (connected to pin 4) heats up extremely when I boot up the pi. I'm not sure what's the problem, I wired the two sensors identically, but the only difference is they use different VCC pins, GND pins, and Echo and Trig pins.

Comment: Here are some pictures if they help: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Cw1IAwGDgNI_b2StyqLrxCsw8L5kJKp7

Comment: The sensor that is heating up is the second one, on the right if you look at the pictures. I'd also like to note that when I used the same ground (34) and VCC (4) pins that I used for the second sensor (the one that is heating up) for the first sensor instead of its original pins (2 and 6 respectively), the first sensor also heats up.

Comment: It's not a faulty sensor either because I've tried multiple others and still achieved the same result.

Comment: Photos only help a little - some wires snake into dark places.